# Django using foreignKey to retrieve one attribute in a query

Tags: django, filter, models

In my django code I have these two objects :

```
class A(models.Model):
  ...

class B(models.Model)
  flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  type = models.ForeignKey(A)
  ...
```

I'd like to do something like :

A.objects.filter(...)

in my filter I'd like to only have the A whose has at least 1 B with the flag = True linked.
Is it possible to do this directly using the filter ? rather than having a loop and then :

```
a.b_set.filter(flag__exact=1).count() > 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying `b__flag=...` will give you what you want.

```
A.objects.filter(b__flat=True)
```

Above could yield duplicated `A` objects. Prevent that, use [`QuerySet.distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct):

```
A.objects.filter(b__flat=True).distinct()
```